# Is Fubini's theorem the right way to solve this?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I was given this integral: $$\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^\infty \frac{y\arctan(xy)}{(1+y^2)(1+x^2y^2)} dy dx $$

I tried using Fubini to change the integration order and what I got was:

$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{(\arctan(y^2) - \arctan(0))}{2(1+y^2)}dy $$ and I cannot integrate further, is this how I should have solved this integral?

Comment: what is the context? have you considered to do it numerically?

Comment: Note that $\arctan(0) = 0$, so you can "ignore" that part.

Comment: @Mark I do ignore it when I move to the next step. Just showed it as this was the process I did...

Comment: @user190080 It can be done numerically but as this is a home assignment I highly doubt this was my TA intent

Comment: There's a mistake in your integration with respect to $x$. It's not $\arctan(y^2)$, but $\arctan(y)^2$.  And you should have lost the factor of $y$ in the numerator.  After these corrections, the integral is straighforward.

Comment: @B.Goddard the y factor is my typo, correcting it now. THX!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second integral should have the square outside the arctan. And $\arctan(0)$ is $0$, so your answer is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(y)^2}{1+y^2}dy = \frac{1}{6}(\arctan(\infty)^3-\arctan(0)^3) = \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^3  
$$